Is it possible to use service principal to access TFVC repository on azure?
I have a TFVC repository hosted on Microsoft Azure repos within an organization.
I want to be able to automatically run TF.exe commands via a batch script on a self hosted pipeline agent.
Is it possible to use service principal to run these commands?  PAT is not working when trying these commands as it opens a login screen in the browser when we attempt to run the commands.

Using the System.AccessToken in the pipeline is convenient.

You don't need to use service principal to run tf commands on a self-hosted pipeline agent. You can use the System.AccessToken, which is a special variable that carries the security token used by the running build.
Here are the steps:

Create a new pipeline with the TFVC source. (You should turn off the Disable creation of classic build pipelines option in the Project Settings > Pipelines > Settings)

Please note that the TFVC source should be the TFVC repo that you want to use the TF command against.


Navigate to the job, under Additional options, check the Allow scripts to access the OAuth token box.


Then in the pipeline, the checkout step will create a workspace with the build service account projectname Build Service (orgname). The System.AccessToken we will use is from the build service account.


In the PowerShell task, run the script with tf command.
Example script:


tf history * /noprompt /recursive /stopafter:5  /loginType:OAuth  /login:.,$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN


tf workspaces /owner:* /computer:* /format:detailed /collection:https://dev.azure.com/orgname/ /noprompt /loginType:OAuth /login:.,$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN

tf workspace /delete  "workspacename;ownername" /collection:https://dev.azure.com/orgname/  /loginType:OAuth  /login:.,$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN


Please note that the build service account will need the necessary permissions to perform certain operations. For example, to delete another user's workspace, the Administer permission is required. This can be achieved by adding the build service account to the Project Collection Administrators group.
Update：

Running this "tf workspaces /owner:* /computer:* /format:detailed /collection:https://dev.azure.com/XXXXCloudCollection/ /noprompt /loginType:OAuth /login:.,$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" after the pipeline does a get latest, I still get the tf30063. I added this as just an inline batch script step.

So, you are using the inline batch script. In this case, you should change the $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN to %SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN%.
tf workspaces /owner:* /computer:* /format:detailed /collection:https://dev.azure.com/orgname/ /noprompt /loginType:OAuth /login:.,%SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN%


When use a variable in a script, we should use environment variable syntax. Different platform's syntax for referencing an environment variable is different. Here is the example:


When we try to use that we get a TF30063 error.  Please see below.
2024-07-15T13:55:51.4843667Z D:\ADO-Release-1_work\r1>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer"\TF workspace /delete LDS /collection:https://dev.azure.com/ZZZZclollection/ /noprompt /loginType:OAuth /login:.,$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
2024-07-15T13:55:52.4410545Z TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com/ZZZZclollection.

Hi @Sherpa11, the TFVC source should be the TFVC repo that you want to use the TF command against. In your error message, the organization is ZZZZclollection. Then you need to create a pipeline in the project of this ZZZZclollection  and choose the TFVC repo that you need to run the tf command as source code. I have updated the answer with more details.

Running this "tf workspaces /owner:* /computer:* /format:detailed /collection:https://dev.azure.com/XXXXCloudCollection/ /noprompt /loginType:OAuth /login:.,$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" after the pipeline does a get latest I still get the tf30063.  I added this as just an inline batch script step.

Hi @Sherpa11, can you try to change the $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN to %SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN% in your inline batch script step and see if it works?

Hi @Sherpa11, it seems some comments is deleted by system. May I know if this answer works after you change the $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN to %SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN% in your inline batch script step?
